# Are there male Maledictuses?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, maledictus

In the description for Maledictuses in the Harry Potter/Fantastic Beasts sticker album, it says

> A Maledictus is a wizard or witch with a blood curse that transforms them into a beast.

However, the Harry Potter Wiki says that Maledictuses are only female.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No, Maledictuses are only female.

J.K. Rowling said [over Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/1044584072285052930) that Maledictuses are only women, and their hereditary curse is passed through the female line.

[image: transcription below]

> **@TibsThickTail**: So would lycanthropy be a strain/branch of maledictus or is it its own thing entirely?
>
> **@jk_rowling**: They're different conditions. Maledictuses are always women, whereas werewolves can be either sex. The Maledictus carries a blood curse from birth, which is passed down from mother to daughter.

So, J.K. Rowling currently says there are no male Maledictuses, though this isn’t stated anywhere in “official” canon where it would be more difficult to change, like the movies or in their official screenplays, yet.

Comment: Why not "Maledictae", then.

Comment: @Mal It doesn’t begin with _mal-_, though, but with _male-_; where _bene-dictus_ (‘well-said’) means ‘blessed’, _male-dictus_ (‘evilly-said’) means ‘cursed’. _Fred-edictus_ would mean ‘declared by Fred’, which would be a bit tame. Spencer’s point is a good one, though – if it’s only women, it ought to be a _Maledicta_ (feminine), not a _Maledictus_ (masculine).